# Transfer / switch / change values of two columns, if one columns is 0 / NaN

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following dataframe df:

```
Name   A    B
Apple  0.0  22.0
Ban    1.0  0.0
Ap    -2.0  1.0
```

The desired outcome would be:

```
Name   A    B    
Apple  22.0  22.0
Ban    1.0  1.0  
Ap    -2.0  1.0
```

Right now I am doing a nested `np.where` combination, which also works:

```
df['C'] = np.where(df['A'] == 0, df['B'], df['A'])
df['C'] = np.where(df['B'] == 0, df['A'], df['B'])
```

is there a better way to do it?

Comment: adjusted the desired outcome, now it makes more sense

Comment: If both are non-empty, I keep both values

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One idea is test if at least one `0` per rows and then repalce values by `sum` with [`DataFrame.mask`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.mask.html):

```
cols = ['A','B']
df[cols] = df[cols].mask(df[cols].eq(0).any(axis=1), df.sum(axis=1), axis=0)
print (df)
    Name     A     B
0  Apple  22.0  22.0
1    Ban   1.0   1.0
2     Ap  -2.0  -1.0
```

Your solution should be changed with [`DataFrame.assign`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html) for avoid overwrite columns:

```
df = df.assign(A = np.where(df['A'] == 0, df['B'], df['A']),
               B = np.where(df['B'] == 0, df['A'], df['B']))
```

---

```
df = df.assign(A = df['B'].where(df['A'] == 0, df['A']),
               B = df['A'].where(df['B'] == 0, df['B']))

print (df)
    Name     A     B
0  Apple  22.0  22.0
1    Ban   1.0   1.0
2     Ap  -2.0  -1.0
```

Comment: sorry I adjusted the desired outcome